# SQL Join Between different tables

Tags: sql, join

I have 4 tables:

- Customers
- Accounts
- Payments
- Transfers

I want to get the customers that made either transfer or a payment. Payment table is linked to customers table, transfer table is linked to accounts table, and accounts table is linked to customers table.

How can I write the query that returns the customers that made either a payment or a transfer?

```
SELECT customer.registration_os, Count(DISTINCT customer.customer_id) AS registrations 
FROM customer
Inner Join account On customer.customer_id = account.customer_id
INNER JOIN payment ON customer.customer_id = payment.customer_id 
LEFT JOIN transfer ON customer.customer_id= transfer.from_account 
WHERE customer.ts_created BETWEEN ? AND ? 
  AND customer.registration_source = ? 
GROUP BY customer.registration_os
```

Thank you

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result (as well formatted text.) Also show us your current query attempt!

Comment: You should try something before asking directly....

Comment: Kindly have a look on [how to ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Learn the basics about `JOIN` here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/1008/join - Also, please specify your RDBMS. I've assumed MSSQL for now.

Comment: I posted the query that i was using

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Customers as t1 
LEFT JOIN Accounts as t2 ON t2.customer_id = t1.id // (Account table is linked to Customers)
LEFT JOIN Payments as t3 ON t3.customer_id = t3.id //  (Payments table is linked to Customers)
LEFT JOIN Transfers as t4 ON t4.account_id = t2.id // (Transfers table is linked to Accounts)
WHERE (condition)
```

For Condition use parameter based on table name here i have given t1, t2 , t3, t4 you can use any table in condition.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the customers that made either transfer or a payment

In SQL, `UNION` is analogous to logical `OR`:

```
  SELECT customer_id
    FROM customer NATURAL JOIN account
  UNION
  SELECT customer_id
    FROM customer NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT from_account AS customer_id 
                                    FROM transfer ) t
```